# What is the Difference between @PeculiarVentures 's `webcrypto` and `node-webcrypto-ossl`?

Tags: webcrypto

I'm the author of GUN and I love your work!

I'm a little bit confused about which libraries I should be using, or which ones depend on each other:

- `node-webcrypto-ossl`
- `webcrypto`
- `webcrypto-core`
- `node-webcrypto-p11`

Or any other ones I should know about.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`webcrypto-core` is a common layer library to be used by all webcrypto libraries for input validation. It doesn't implement any crypto providers. You can use this library if you want to implement own crypto provider.

`@peculiar/webcrypto` is WebCrypto API implementation based on NodeJS Crypto API. It's easy to install

`node-webcrypto-ossl` is NodeJS addon which implements WebCrypto API based on OpenSSL. Requires C++ tools for compilation.

`node-webcrypto-p11` is WebCrypto API implementation based on PKCS#11
All these 3 crypto libraries are for NodeJS projects using. Requires PKCS#11 library.